Fixing Errors When Running 'expo-start' in React Native Project
I have error when i try type command 'npx expo-start'. Previously it's working properly before i try to

install react-native-progress
make splash screen with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05V_uB7RZXo

Error result
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Ray'
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
        at errorMessage (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:38:39)
        at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:201:13)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
        at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
        at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
        at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
      var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                              ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
        at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
        at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
        at process.emit (events.js:305:20)
        at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:164:25)
    Install for [ 'expo-start@latest' ] failed with code 7

Please help me, how can i do to fix this problem 

can you share the code in expo snack so that we can check

@GauravRoy thank you bro, but the issue has been fixed :)
